# What's the best way to create public profile and content forms?

Tags: users, user-profile

It's great to have Craft CMS on SE at last!

We're working on a Craft site that'll allow public visitors to register, maintain a profile, and create entries in an Events channel.

Should we create individual user templates (signup, profile, content), or is there a more automatic way to do this with Craft?

For example, some of our profile fields are dropdown menus, but they don't seem to render as form dropdowns without us manually recoding them to do so. Is this correct?

Look forward to some great answers!

Answer (score 5):

User registration works just like front-end entry editing. You build the form on any page you like, and submit it to the action "users/saveUser".

All fields need to be coded by you, and extra profile fields can be filled in by setting the input name to "fields[handle]".

The Craft Documentation has an [example registration form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form). The also have an [example for allowing users to update their profile](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-profile-form).